# Connecting to EC2 instance via CloudShell using its private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudshell

I am trying to connecting to an EC2 instance via CloudShell.

When I use its public IPv4 DNS it works but when I use its private IP I get the following message:

> connect to host 172.xx.xx.xxx port 22: No route to host

The goal is to dissociate the public ip to save the cost.

The instructions provided are clear:

[image]

What am I missing?

**LOGS**

```
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 172.xx.xx.xx originally 172.xx.xx.xx
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 172.xx.xx.xx is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 172.xx.xx.xx originally 172.xx.xx.xx
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/cloudshell-user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/cloudshell-user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 172.xx.xx.xx [172.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 172.xx.xx.xx port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 172.xx.xx.xx port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: Use session manager instead. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/connect-to-an-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-session-manager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS CloudShell is not running inside your VPC, so there is no way for it to resolve that address to the EC2 instance and connect to it. Only resources inside the VPC can communicate with each other over their private IP addresses.

For an alternative, you should look into use [AWS SSM Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html) to connect to your EC2 instances, instead of SSH. SSM Session Manager can connect to EC2 instances without public IPs, from outside the VPC.